# Mean of every replication

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
set.seed(30)
nsim <- 50    ## NUMBER OF REPLICATIONS
demand <- c(12,13,24,12,13,12,14,10,11,10)

res <- replicate(nsim, {
    load <- runif(10,11,14)
    diff <- load - demand    ## DIFFERENCE BETWEEN DEMAND AND LOAD 
    return(sum(diff < 0))
})
res
[1] 6 5 7 4 4 5 4 3 6 4 5 5 5 4 2 5 3 3 3 5 3 2 4 6 5 4 4 3 5 6 4 4 3 6 5 3 5 5 4 3 3
[42] 6 4 4 4 6 6 5 4 5
```

I have a huge data set and the question is what is the fastest way of calculating the mean for every replication. For example the res in first replication is `6` so the result should be `6/1=6` for the second `(6+5)/2=5.5` for the third `(6+5+7)/3=6` and for the last replication is `sum(res)/nsim=4.38`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the cumulative sum of the result and divide by the sequence of the 'res'

```
cumsum(res)/seq_along(res)
#[1] 6.000000 5.500000 6.000000 5.500000 5.200000 5.166667 5.000000 4.750000 4.888889 4.800000 4.818182 4.833333 4.846154 4.785714 4.600000 4.625000 4.529412
#[18] 4.444444 4.368421 4.400000 4.333333 4.227273 4.217391 4.291667 4.320000 4.307692 4.296296 4.250000 4.275862 4.333333 4.322581 4.312500 4.272727 4.323529
#[35] 4.342857 4.305556 4.324324 4.342105 4.333333 4.300000 4.268293 4.309524 4.302326 4.295455 4.288889 4.326087 4.361702 4.375000 4.367347 4.380000
```

---

Or with `cummean` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
cummean(res)
```

Both the solutions are vectorized and should be fast